# CakePHP REST API (JSON) not giving response when I do var_dump in the controller function

Tags: json, rest, api, response, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to debug one of my controller functions in CakePHP 3.X which is an JSON REST API by dumping some of the data in the server. In our application setup we have Angular on Frontend and CakePHP as backend (REST API). When I try to var_dump some data I'm getting no response for the request on the **browser**. I'm not sure why that is. When I do print_r instead it's giving me the response. I need to see all the errors and exceptions when I call that endpoint but it doesn't give any response when there's an error.

Can someone please help me ?.

Comment: Please can someone help me ?

Comment: add sample code we will check

Comment: Depending on what you're var_dump'ing it could be attempting to generate a very large set of object properties, potentially even circularly referenced ones, that could in theory slow or crash the thread. Checkout cake's global `debug()` function as an alternative https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/debugging.html#basic-debugging

Comment: Thanks @Gowthaman. I'll add a sample code to the Question.

Comment: Thanks @ahoffner ! :-)